# Using (Reverse) Monotone Convergence Theorem on a sequence of function where index approaches zero

Tags: real-analysis

This is my first post so please let me know how much more detail should I provide.

So the question is from Real Analysis: Modern Techniques and Their Applications by G.B. Folland.
The problem statement is as follows:

(Problem 6.8b) Suppose $\mu(X)=1$ and $f\in L^p$ for some $p>0$, so that $f\in L^q$ for $0<q<p$. Show $(\int|f|^q-1)/q\geq \log||f||_q$ and $(\int|f|^q-1)/q\to\int\log|f|$ as $q\to 0$.

Approach I have so far:

The first inequality is fairly trivial as it comes directly from the relationship between $\log x$ and $x-1$. The second equality pretty much asks readers (at least in my opinion) to use Monotone Convergence Theorem. I have already shown that $\lim_{q\to 0}\frac{|f|^q-1}{q}\to\log |f|^q$ and argue that $\frac{|f|^q-1}{q}$ is a non-decreasing through derivative argument. I though I have all the necessities to apply Monotone Convergence Theorem but realized that the theorem specifically states that the $\lim_{n\to\infty}$ carries over the integral. However in my case I want $q\to 0$ instead of $q\to\infty$.

Although I also know there exists the Reverse Monotone Convergence Theorem (with additional requirement of each integral to be finite), but when I try to view the sequence as $q\to 0$ as a monotone decreasing sequence, i.e. $a_1=(|f|^q-1)/q$, $\;a_2={|f|^{q-1}-1}/(q-1)$, ..., etc. then my index does not approach infinity. I would like to know how can I exactly use (Reverse) Monotone Convergence Theorem when the limit does not necessarily approach infinity. Or if I can even use it or not in this problem. Or if there is a better approach.

Sorry for the long post, and thank you in advance.

==================================================

First I want to thank you for the hint, it does help alot.

However after I finished the proof and reviewed it again, I noticed that there is one missing condition: the function must be non-negative in order to use the Monotone Convergence Theorem.

But I am unable to convince myself that $(|f|^q-1)/q$ is always non-negative, can I get a hint or clarification?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**:
$$f_n=\frac{|f|^{\frac{1}{n}}-1}{\frac{1}{n}}$$

Comment: Thanks alot, can't believe I didn't think of this :)